# UISearchBar appearing above tableview

Tags: objective-c, tableview, uisearchbar

I have a tabBarcontroller, and within it I have several navigation controllers that lead to tableview controllers. Now, if I drop a uisearchbar at the top of any of the tableviews, when I load up the project, the uisearchbar appears above the tableview (at a negative content offset, JUST ABOVE the screen). Now here's the weird part--if I click on different tabs a few times and then come back to the tab with the uitableview controller, the contentoffset problem is gone. Why? And what can I do to fix it?

Comment: What is the sequence of elements inside the ViewController layout? Is it UITableView then UISearchbar? I mean the sequence of this http://i.stack.imgur.com/b9Zxq.png

Comment: It's very weird, I'll probaly just put searchbar in cell. not ideal but idk what's going on

Comment: Why do you add the searchbar inside the tableview? if you want searchbar inside tableview, then add it as a TableView Header

Comment: right, if you drag and drop then it's a problem. so its a problem as a header

Comment: Tableview->uinavigationcontroller->{searchbar,tableview} I said it wrong sorry